# Redux-saga - TypeScript error with TakeEvery: TakeableChannel<unknown>

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a simple redux saga.

```js
import { api } from '../api';
import * as screen from './slice';
import { fetchScreenSuccess } from './slice';

interface fetchScreenPayload {
  screenName: string;
}

interface fetchScreenAction {
  type: string;
  payload: fetchScreenPayload;
}

function* fetchScreen(api: any, action: fetchScreenAction) {
  ...
}

export default function* watchDataSource() {
  yield takeEvery(screen.fetchScreen, fetchScreen, api);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   Argument of type 'ActionCreatorWithoutPayload<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel<unknown>'.
  Property 'take' is missing in type 'ActionCreatorWithoutPayload<string>' but required in type 'TakeableChannel<unknown>'.
}
```

The slice is:

```js
export const screenSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'screen',
  // `createSlice` will infer the state type from the `initialState` argument
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchScreen(state): any {
      state.screen = initialState.screen;
      state.isLoading = true;
    },
  },
});
```

Any idea of how to remove the typescript error?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two problems with your code:

1. You are calling the `takeEvery` wrongly. It should accept the action type as the first argument, and then any number of generator functions. I'm not sure what `screen.fetchScreen` does, and it's not clear what the `fetchScreen` and the `api` are there. But every arguments after the first one should be a generator function.
2. Your generator function `fetchScreen` accepts `(api: any, action: fetchScreenAction)` and it should accept just the action. You could pass the `api` through the action somehow.

**You could write it like this:**

```
interface fetchScreenPayload {
  screenName: string;
  api: string;
}

interface fetchScreenAction {
  type: string;
  payload: fetchScreenPayload;
}
function* fetchScreen(action: fetchScreenAction) {
  ...
}

export default function* watchDataSource() {
  yield takeEvery('SOME_TYPE_TO_MATCH_YOUR_ACTION', fetchScreen);
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args) says that the `pattern` parameter can be a function and any number of extra `args` can be passed to the sub-saga. Imho the code from the question is clean and the problem looks like [these various signatures](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/main/packages/core/types/ts3.6/effects.d.ts#L180-L211) aren't well discriminated by Typescript without an extra type somewhere, which I'm actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it have to do with the type of the sub saga `action` argument. Without it, typescript is not able to pick the right [function signature for `takeEvery`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/main/packages/core/types/ts3.6/effects.d.ts#L180-L211) and fallbacks to one requiring a channel as the first parameter.

```
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
function* fetchScreen(api: any, action: PayloadAction) {
  ...
}
```

Credits to https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/2336#issuecomment-1307268267